# Use model to predict the next word using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I train a "Recurrent Neural Networks" following the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) and got a model:

```
model/
model/model.ckpt-72985.data-00000-of-00001
model/model.ckpt-72883.meta
model/model.ckpt-72793.meta
model/model.ckpt-72985.meta
model/model.ckpt-72793.index
model/model.ckpt-72971.data-00000-of-00001
model/events.out.tfevents.1488038213.mymachine
model/model.ckpt-72883.index
model/model.ckpt-72985.index
model/graph.pbtxt
model/model.ckpt-72883.data-00000-of-00001
model/model.ckpt-72793.data-00000-of-00001
model/model.ckpt-72971.index
model/model.ckpt-72971.meta
model/checkpoint
```

Now, I want to use this model to predict the next word in a program, how do I do it?.

I want to use a function such as nextWord("What is the next word?") to return the predicted word.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `tf.train.Saver`.

```
saved_model = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('./model/') #or your model path
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, saved_model.model_checkpoint_path)
```

Also you might want to have a look at [this example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/save_restore_model.py)

Comment: I do not have file with ckpt extension.